# Is this map a quotient map?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and $\pi: X \to Y$ the quotient map generated by $\tau_Y$, the topology of $Y$. $U \subset X$ is an open or closed subset, saturated respect to $\pi$ (i.e. $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))=U$). Show that $\pi|_U: U \to \pi(U)$ is also a quotient map.

I have tried but I've just proved it for $U$ open, if U is closed I can't prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a useful lemma which gives a condition on when a restriction is a quotient map.

> Let $\pi:X\to Y$ be a quotient map and $A\subset X$ with $B=\pi[A]$, where $A$ and $B$ have the subspace topologies. Then $π|_A:A\to B$ is a quotient map if and only if:
>   (i) Each subset of $A$ which is saturated and open in $A$ is the intersection of $A$ with a saturated and open subset of $X$.
>   (ii) The same with 'open' replaced by 'closed'.

Now if $U$ is closed and saturated, then each closed and saturated subset of $U$ is clearly closed and saturated in $X$, so we can apply the lemma.

A direct proof:
If $U$ is closed saturated, and $D\subseteqπ(U)$ such that $C:=π|_U^{-1}(D)$ is closed in $U$, then $C$ is closed in $X$. Now $π^{-1}(D)=\{x\in X,π(x)\in D\}=\{x\in U,π(x)\in D\}
=C$. So $D$ has a closed preimage, thus is itself closed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: a surjective map is a quotient map if and only if the closed sets are precisely those with closed preimages.